# Can I do multiple dataLayer pushes for a single transaction in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I've set up tracking when a user completes a purchase. Right now, I'm doing multiple dataLayer pushes -- I do a push for the order total and then a seperate push for each product in the cart:

```js
dataLayer.push({
    'total': total
});

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const product = data[i];

    dataLayer.push({
        'name': product.name,
        'price': product.price,
        'quantity': product.quantity,
        'sku': product.sku
    });
}
```

Is this acceptable? I see in some examples the entire purchase being pushed as a single push (i.e. array of products). Does GTM behave the same in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

Your example will not work.

GTM updates the internal state of variables only when you push a key called "event" to the datalayer. Your example does not have an "event" key, so GTM will not even noticed that you pushed something, at least until some other event happens later on.

Even if you added an event, your example would still not work as expected.

Since you push the product data with the keys name, price etc. to the top level of the datalayer, they will be overwritten with each new push (since you cannot have duplicate keys in the datalayer).

What you would do instead is add products to their own array within your loop, and then push the whole array to the datalayer:

```
var products = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const product = data[i];
    products.push({
        'name': product.name,
        'price': product.price,
        'quantity': product.quantity,
        'sku': product.sku
    });
};

dataLayer.push({
  "products":products,
  "event":"updateProductData"
});
```

If you want to use this for GA Enhances Ecommerce, it would be best to follow  the advice from the other answer and construct your datalayer according to the specifications in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases).

Comment: Got it. But why doesn't the [documentation on the dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#multipush) mention anything about the data structure while the ecommerce docs does? That's what's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're not following the syntax. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases the products are meant to be neatly stored within very specific structure. Not just pushed into the DL in hope that GTM would magically handle absence of strict structure.